# Dataflow graphs

Tags: frama-c

Is there a frama-c plugin to output interprocedural data flow / points-to graphs?

I understand -pdg from the slicer plugin will include this information, but wondering if I can get it separately.

Answer (score 1):

The PDG is not part of the slicing plug-in, you can use it alone if you wish. See :

```
$ frama-c -pdg-help
```

for a (short) list of options, and the API in the Db.Pdg module (in src/kernel/db.mli) to use it in your own program.